# EC2 hosted Node.js application - can't remotely connect to port

Tags: node.js, proxy, amazon-ec2, node-http-proxy

**Update**: Turns out the only problem was that I was behind a firewall that blocked some ports, but not 8000.

---

Edit: **TL;DR:** can't connect to port 9000 remotely, but port 8000 is ok and I don't know why :(

---

I've got this node.js application that's running on port **8000** and another one ([http-proxy](https://npmjs.org/package/http-proxy)) running on port **9000**.

Running them on my machine is fine, but I have some problems when I put them up on a server (**EC2** instance - I did open the ports in the web console security group<sup>[1]</sup>). The application works fine, but I can't connect to the proxy from outside. I tried to `$ telnet localhost 9000` on the server and it connects, so I guess that's a good sign.

Another thing that I have noticed is that if I try to run the applications separately, I get the same results, i.e.: 8000 - OK, 9000 - NOTOK :<.
However, if I change the port the proxy uses from 9000 to 8000, it works. And if I switch the ports, i.e. application:9000 and proxy:8000, I can connect to the proxy, but not to the application. I have also tried other numbers, but that wouldn't fix it either.

I guess there's something really stupid that has nothing to do with the application itself and that I'm missing, but I can't put my finger on it, so does anyone have any idea why this setup doesn't work?

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express.io');
var app = module.exports = express();

require('./proxy');

app.http().io();
app.listen(8000);
// ...
```

**proxy.js**

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var url = require('url');

httpProxy.createServer(function(req, res, proxy) {

    // ... 
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
        host: destination.host,
        port: 80
    });

}).listen(9000);
```

`$ netstat -pln | grep node` output

```
tcp   0      0      0.0.0.0:9000    0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN  1487/node
tcp   0      0      0.0.0.0:8000    0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN  1487/node
```

**Security group rules**

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you configure your ec2 instance to have port 9000 open?

Comment: @sheldonk yes, I did, and I'm certain (not sure how I can show it in here, though).
At the moment, I've `iptables -F`'d and it's all working fine ...

Comment: You also need to make sure port 9000 is open in your EC2 security group - this is something that I believe has to happen before the instance is launched the first time, but not sure.

Comment: @Joe yes, port 9000 is open in the security group (I've added a screenshot in the question). As for the rules needed to be set before the first launch, it seems that it's not the case: [security groups docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2007-08-29/DeveloperGuide/distributed-firewall-concepts.html).

Comment: <suggestion>You can use `nginx` as reverse proxy and upstream your app.</suggestion>

Comment: Do you access the EC2 instance through a load balancer or directly ?

Comment: Can you update the post with the answer and mark it as the Accepted Answer

Comment: @DavidLevesque I was accessing it directly, no load balancers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was not at all related to the application or the EC2 instance setup.

The network I was in while testing this was blocking some ports. This is why when moving the proxy to port `8000` it was working fine, but on `9000` or any other random ones that I tried it wasn't. D'oh!