# not able to connect to ubuntu instance t1.micro after ec2-authorize

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I installed an application jetty on ubuntu 12.04 instance t1.micro

```
PUBLIC_DNS = ec2-54-225-24-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I can do:

```
ssh ec2-54-225-24-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

From within the instance, I can do:

```
curl localhost:8080 -- Success
curl 127.0.0.1:8080 -- Success
```

From DEVELOPMENT DESKTOP, I did:

```
ec2-authorize "quicklaunch-0" -P tcp -p 8080
GROUP quicklaunch-0
PERMISSION quicklaunch-0 ALLOWS tcp 8080 8080 FROM CIDR 0.0.0.0/0 ingress
```

And when I try to connect from browser:

```
http://$PUBLIC_DNS:8080 or curl $PUBLIC_DNS:8080, it does not connect

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I can connect to port 22 of the instance from my desktop.

My instance belongs to quicklaunch-0

What is it I am missing? Please help.

Based on: [EC2 hosted Node.js application - can't remotely connect to port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288567/ec2-hosted-node-js-application-cant-remotely-connect-to-port)

I did try various other ports and launching new instances. Nothing seems to work.

EDIT:

When I run netstat -l, my output is:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN
```

Is FOREIGN address a problem here?

Comment: Your application may not be listening to the correct IP. Ec2 uses NAT and the ip assigned directly to your instance is a private one. Software firewalls can also interfere.

Comment: I think my jetty server is an issue. I dont think its an ec2 issue. I will edit once investigation complete

Comment: It appears to be only listening on localhost.

Comment: thx...yes...that was an issue. I will do man netstat to learn

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my post, netstat -ln revealed that my app server was listening only to localhost. I fixed that.